# How to use .count to calculate number of times each item in one list appears in another list in python?

Tags: python

I am attempting to calculate the number of times each item in one list appears in another list using python's .count. This is what I have:

```
tentslist = ['E4', 'C2', 'C8', 'G8', 'G1', 'A7', 'C5', 'G4', 'A5', 'E1', 'E6', 'A3']
x1t = ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'A6', 'A7', 'A8']

print(x1t.count(tentslist[0-11]))
```

The output I am looking for is 3, however I am getting 0. Why is this? How do I fix this?

Thankyou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is it's looking to count the amount of times the entire tentslist is in x1t. Which is indeed 0.

What you seem to want is how many times an element from x1t is in tentslist? Then this will be a solution

```
tentslist = ['E4', 'C2', 'C8', 'G8', 'G1', 'A7', 'C5', 'G4', 'A5', 'E1', 'E6', 'A3']
x1t = ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'A6', 'A7', 'A8']

count = 0
for x in x1t:
    count += tentslist.count(x)

print(count)
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be achive by using the list comprehension

```
count = sum([x1t.count(x) for x in tentslist])
```

This is at first counting the occurences for each element and later on sums them to get the total result

Edit: As suggested in the comments one can also remove the list comprehension entirely and just uses this

```
count = sum(x1t.count(x) for x in tentslist)
```

Comment: The list is useless - in fact it adds complexity. Remove the square brackets, and the result will be the same. The thing is that `sum` takes an *iterable*, which can be a list, but can also be a generator, and a generator expression as well.

Answer (score 2):

you need intersection?

```
len( set(x1t) & set(tentslist) )
```

Output:3

Answer (score 0):

Following is the syntax for count() method:
list.count(obj)
obj is the object to be counted in the list.

Your code will return not null only there:

```
tentslist = ['E4', 'C2', 'C8', 'G8', 'G1', 'A7', 'C5', 'G4', 'A5', 'E1', 'E6', 'A3']
x1t = ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'A6', 'A7', 'A8', ['E4', 'C2', 'C8', 'G8', 'G1', 'A7', 'C5', 'G4', 'A5', 'E1', 'E6', 'A3']]

print(x1t.count(tentslist))

output: 1
```

Use:

```
tentslist = ['E4', 'C2', 'C8', 'G8', 'G1', 'A7', 'C5', 'G4', 'A5', 'E1', 'E6', 'A3']
x1t = ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'A6', 'A7', 'A8']
matches = set(x1t) & set(tentslist)
match_count = len(matches)
```

Answer (score 0):

sum(tentslist.count(x) for x in x1t)